# DBeaver+Oracle: Turn Off IP to Hostname Resolution

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

For some weird reason DBeaver 21.0.2 with Oracle-driver 12.2.0.1 seems to take a configured IP-address as the host, turn it into a hostname and then use that hostname for further usage to connect to the database.

That clearly is undesired as I access that database from an external workplace and with all the additional networking going on the IP-address clearly would be the way to go for me.

To make this even weirder, that resolution seems to take place *after* the connection was established. I mean I had a typo in the service name at one point and I got an ORA-12514 instead. As soon as I fixed that typo I got back to the hostname resolution problem, which has no ORA-number. So this might be something in DBeaver then.

DBeaver's error protocol:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: myunknowndbhost.sjngm.com
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:126)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:161)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:521)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:660)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:639)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:189)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.lambda$0(JDBCDataSource.java:176)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:195)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.oracle.model.OracleDataSource.openConnection(OracleDataSource.java:150)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.initializeMainContext(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:100)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.<init>(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:59)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.initializeRemoteInstance(JDBCDataSource.java:109)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:97)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.<init>(JDBCDataSource.java:89)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.oracle.model.OracleDataSource.<init>(OracleDataSource.java:84)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.oracle.OracleDataSourceProvider.openDataSource(OracleDataSourceProvider.java:147)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.connect(DataSourceDescriptor.java:896)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:70)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectionTestJob.run(ConnectionTestJob.java:103)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

So the question is: how do I turn off this hostname resolution?

Answer (score 0):

This might be Oracle Client behavior... During user authentication, all Oracle Database clients are required to report a "MACHINE" variable to the server, describing the client's hostname/IP - this is what's reported in the `machine` column of the `v$session` database view. And I think the JDBC thin client will do a reverse DNS lookup to try to fill in that variable if necessary.

You can try setting the `v$session.machine` [OracleConnection Property](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html)... in DBeaver, edit your connection, click "Edit Driver Settings" on the Connection Settings page, click "Driver properties" tab, and add a new property named `v$session.machine` with whatever name you want as the value.

Or you could try setting the `ORACLE_HOSTNAME` environment variable to your hostname. I'm unclear whether this would get picked up by the Oracle JDBC driver or not, but [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ntcli/oracle-database-client-network-topics.html#GUID-B4869D2E-36D0-450C-8FE2-941FC24262C7) might be suggesting that it could help?

You could also try adding a hostname for your IP address in your HOSTS file. That seems the most likely fix this, but it's the most annoying option to implement.

Comment: I tried your second paragraph, but it didn't make it work.